# Magento 2 - Category XML update to use custom list.phtml file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Using this code in the category XML update works to use my customlist.phtml file instead of the default list.phtml file.

But the problem is the category title and description are repositioned to the bottom of the page. I need them to be at the default position which should be at the top of the listed products.. what am i missing..

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
    <block name="product_list" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/customlist.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in you .XML file.

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/customlist.phtml">
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```